# Read permission issue with moved uploaded files on IIS

Tags: php, iis, permissions, windows-server-2008, directory-structure

I have a PHP 5.4 served website on a Plesk-based IIS 7.5 server. The app pool identity runs as `IWAM_plesk` but PHP runs as `IUSR_username`.

When I upload files, PHP can move the file and create a thumbnail from it, but the file doesn't gain the anonymous `IWAM_plesk(default)` permissions for browsers to read the file and thus the image (not the generated thumbnail) "cannot be read" when viewing the site.

How can I grant the correct permissions to the file after uploading?

Only a folder *"replace permissions on all child objects"* fixes the issue (or adding the user permissions directly to the file).

Answer (score 2):

This is a problem of the `upload_tmp_dir` setting in php.ini. When moving a file during the upload process, the permission don't move with it. Create a project specific upload folder, set the users/groups as you need it and set this folder as `upload_tmp_dir`, either in php.ini or project specific.

The uploaded file will inherit the permissions of the folder.

Had this problem with the webplatform installer, which sets the upload_tmp_dir to C:\Windows\temp by default.